# how to get a value from serialized data in the DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

i try to get a value from serialized data in the mysql of my woocommerce template but I couldn't succeed. What path should I follow?

Here is data in the DB;

```
('meta_id' => '3307','post_id' => '426','meta_key' => 'mphb_season_prices','meta_value' => 'a:12:{i:0;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"252";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:1;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"253";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:2;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"254";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:3;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"255";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:493;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:4;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"256";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:493;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:5;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"257";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:708;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:6;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"258";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:893;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:7;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"259";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:893;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:8;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"260";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:708;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:9;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"261";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:565;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:10;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"262";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:465;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}i:11;a:2:{s:6:"season";s:3:"263";s:5:"price";a:4:{s:7:"periods";a:1:{i:0;i:1;}s:6:"prices";a:1:{i:0;d:422;}s:17:"enable_variations";b:0;s:10:"variations";a:0:{}}}}')
```

Comment: the source data is PHP serialized data so i also added the PHP tag..  MySQL can't handle or parse that so you would need to stream all table data/record data to PHP to process and search in.. So the best is to consider using  beter approaches as [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) or using JSON which MySQL can select/parse/search on..

Comment: sorry this is your first comment? I was editing the question. Please check question again. 
And ty for new tag

Comment: *"sorry this is your first comment? I was editing the question. Please check question again."* mine comment suggestions are still valid after the question edit..

Comment: What is the season  `$foo = array_column($var, 'price', 'season')` then `$foo[$season]['prices'][0]`  [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/308356f8bbc519fe8d4edaf7ccf6907b615af0c4)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  OMG! you are seriously awesome. Thank you from the bottom of my heart. But i have a little problem. I have to make it special for every room! how to make it? please check final look of my shortcode from the above.(EDIT 3)
i just want to ask one more question. i have 12 seasons and i am going to create a price table. So should i make shortcode for each season separately? or can i make this single shorcode?

Comment: you can do it in one and use attributes, just look up a tutorial on that.

Comment: Word Press should unserialize it for you, check the value after getting it from `get_post_meta` - like this `print_r($var);`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Hi again, i tried as your said but I get this error message; 

    Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in 
    /home/...

bro i edit my database data and the final version of the my shortcode above. I've been trying for 4 days and I can't. I would appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: Well for the error obviously $var is false, why that is I cannot know.  Maybe that's ok maybe it's not, etc. I have no way to know this.  I would suggest looking at the value in the DB.  If it's ok, you can simply do an if to exclude doing array column on a non-array value `if($var) array_column($var....)` etc.  Or `if(!$var) return '';` etc...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix "why that is I cannot know"  actually you can check Value above :)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix by the way i have to say when try to get serialized value directly (please check Edit 4) output is empty.

Comment: `why that is I cannot know" actually you can check Value above`  - that's not true, you wouldn't get that error if it was the value above, it must be a boolean for you to have that error, why it's boolean I cannot know. `output is empty` its probably boolean false, not empty (false is empty, but empty is not false) if you output with `var_dump` it will tell you the type.  String is empty, false is boolean, something will convert to string for output such as var_export or print_r and when they do it converts the false to an empty value.

Comment: In anycase this is an indication that something is wrong in your serialized array, it's really hard to edit them by hand so avoid doing that,  You shouldn't have to manually use `$var    = unserialize($var);`  WP should do this for you automatically when you use `get_post_meta` as I said before

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ty again for your interesting. well i tried above function (Edit 5) and output is array(0){} this is normal?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if add "true" to function then output: string(0)""

Comment: Your sure that `get_the_ID()` post has the meta data?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes i am sure. because i try  *** $post_id = 417; get_post_meta( $post_id,  'mphb_season_prices', true); *** and result is same.  By the way please check my new question. there are all versions I have tried

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ohh so sorry if i try *** $post_id = 417; get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mphb_season_prices', true); ***  output is array(0){}

Comment: I still don't believe the row has the data, you should check in PHPmyAdmin, or for example `SELECT * FROM {prefix}postmeta WHERE post_id=417 AMD meta_key = "mphb_season_prices"` WHERE `{prefix}` is the prefix for your wordpress tables (typically `wp_`)  Everything you shown me indicates that the meta data is not what you think it is, maybe you saved over it at some point while testing etc.  For example to get an output of `array(0){}` your database value would be `a:0:{}` for the serialized data.  it's `{type}:{length}:{value}`  so `a` is array, `0` is length 0 and empty `{}` is the value.

Comment: For example if you see `s:4:"text"` it's type=string : length=4 : value="text".  Therefor to get what you have, the value must not be what you think it is.  Your first problem was doing both `unserialize` and `get_post_meta`.  Now your problem is you "probably" saved a bad value to the DB when you were testing this.  The third argument for `get_post_meta` is some stupid legacy stuff, you almost always want it set to true.  Otherwise if you re-save the metadata you get from it, it will keep nesting it inside another array each time you save it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes bro you were right! I found the problem.  i was using post id of villa page however Plugin Author keeps prices on an external menu page. In this instance post id of the villa page and post id of the prices page are different. Please check my new answer below for results . but unserialize function still doesn't work.  any way!  first off all I have a new problem now :|   I should not write post id for each villa separately. in this case "get_post_meta" is useless for me. damn just trying to create a price table. it shouldn't be that hard! Do you have an idea bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function fiyatlar_shortcode_function() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID(); //get ID of post shortcode is embedded in
    $var = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mphb_season_prices', true ); //retrieve as single
    var_dump($var);
}

add_shortcode( 'fiyat_tablosu', 'fiyatlar_shortcode_function' );
```

You were very close, as I said wordpress will unserialize for you when you use `get_post_meta` there is no need to do this yourself.

The reason for this error

> Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home

Is because WordPress has already unserialized the data into an array.

You most likely will want the 3 argument to be true, otherwise the unserizlized data will be wrapped in an extra array.  For example:

```
 //serialized data (something like this)
 a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}

 //Original data for example
 ["foo" => "bar"]

 //3rd arg true
 ["foo" => "bar"]

 //default OR 3rd arg false -- extra array
 [["foo" => "bar"]]
```

Or something like that.

Oh and don't forget to add the `return $var;` back in ... \(0.o)/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
First of all the data should be converted into a php array using the "unserialize()" or "json_encode" method.

```
$array = unserialize($mydata);
```

and now we pull the price of the season we want by looping over the array.

```
$targetSeason = "259"; //We assign the relevant season id to the variable.
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item["season"] === $targetSeason) {
        $price = $item["price"]["prices"][0]; // We get the price.
        echo "Season $targetSeason price: $price";
        break; // Once we find it, we can end the loop.
    }
}
```